# Django poner en producción con otras paginas html

Tags: python, django

Ya tengo un sitio web con diversas paginas html, quiero usar django para hacer ciertas cosas pero solo en ciertas paginas.

Como quedaría el archivo urls, si solo quiero por ejemplo usar una que sea la de contacto?, las demás paginas quedarían en templates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### No lo haces con Django.

En realidad lo haces desde tu servidor html. Básicamente, la idea es que las páginas `html` **son reales** en el sentido que son archivos que existen en un directorio, mientras que las páginas de Django, se crean y se sirven al instante.

Ya que tus páginas son archivos estáticos, serán tratadas **en producción** del mismo modo que los archivos estáticos de Django y es así: **Django no sirve estáticos**.

> El ejemplo que voy a poner funciona con Nginx, y ya que no indicas que servidor estás usando, si usas otro, deberás buscar esa configuración específica, pero **la idea es la misma en todos**.

En el archivo de configuración de tu sitio, agrega estas líneas.

```
location /paginas_html/ {
  alias /la/ruta/a/esas/paginas/;
}
```

Para terminar, **no haces ningún cambio en tu archivo `urls.py`**.

Answer (score 0):

Exactamente, lo único que puede ser accedido por el cliente son las vistas declaradas en urls.py.
Por ejemplo: si tenes en tu carpeta de templates los archivos index.html, contacto.html y videos.html y solo quieres usar index.html y contacto.html pero no el template de videos, el urls.py quedaría así:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from blog.views import *
from django.contrib import admin

#Establece la url con la direccion a la que debe ser direccionado

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls), # Esto no lo borres porque sino no vas a poder acceder al /admin
    url(r'^$', index, nombre='index'), # Si va al raiz www.tusitio.com que lo atienda el index
    url(r'^contacto/$', contacto, nombre='contactos'), # Si ingresa en www.tusitio.com/contactos entonces sera atendido por la vista de contactos
]
```

Luego en tu views.py de tu app declaras las funciones a ser atendidas cuando los clientes ingresen a las urls especificadas:
Tu views.py quedaría así:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template import loader, Context
from blog.models import *
from django.core import serializers

# Aca se crean tus vistas

def index(request):
    # Codigo que quieras
    return render(request, 'tuapp/index.html')

def contacto(request):
    # Codigo que quieras
    return render(request, 'tuapp/contacto.html')
```

Espero que te haya servido! Saludos!

Comment: Osea que si tengo un sitio con 100 html debo poner los 100 en templates y declarar una url para cada uno, ¿Es correcto?

Comment: Asi es, aunque a veces diferentes urls son atendidas con un mismo template. El urls.py es el equivalente htaccess, que si trabajaste con PHP y apache ya habras visto que se declaran todas las urls